# Styling HTML select element

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c

I have tried everything to remove the default down arrow button from the the SELECT element, but couldn't succeed yet.

I have also tested the background image, that shows behind the default button. And even tried by making NONE as Background, but it's not working for me.

How can I style a select element so the arrow does not appear?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do in all browsers (reliably) without a JavaScript workaround. Not to mention, if you're not careful it will provide a bad UX. The one I prefer for tasteful styling of the select element is:

http://uniformjs.com/

You just need to edit the sprite to look like you want and it'll take care of the rest.

Comment: Yeah thanks but i have my own BG ARROW image to replace, can i do this with this JS?

Comment: The method above does give you the ability to change the arrow. I'd check it out.