# Style HTML select list

Tags: html, css

Got a nice menu with rounded buttons, and I want to style the dropdown list the same way. Tried a lot of different things but there is two things I need some help with:

1. rounded corners like the rest of the buttons.

2. get a solid color, and not that animated look.

Here is a picture showing the buttons and the dropdown:

[image]

Here is the styling on the list:

```
#topNav .right #categoryButton {
     margin-top:5px;
     border:3px solid #fff;
     background-color:#303030 ;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     color: #fff;
     height:50px;
     width:220px;
     outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this question (and its answer) is also the answer you are looking for/were hoping not to find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689389/styling-html-select-element

Comment: To answer this well you must know what browsers are being supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. You have to build your own select element.

From this **[article](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/#article-header-id-4)** discussing "What if you want complete design control?"

> First, try everything you
>   can to make that not necessary. Default form elements are familiar and
>   work well. Making a dropdown menu match the font and colors of your
>   brand isn't usually necessary and is more likely obnoxious at best and
>   bad UX at worst.
>
> If you decide that it's absolutely a good idea to customize a
>   dropdown, then you should use JavaScript to:
>
> 1. Accessibly hide the original select.
> 2. Rebuild the select with custom
>      markup (probably a definition list), that you style how you want.
> 3. Replicate all the functionality that default selects have, which
>      include: keyboard events like up and down arrow keys and return to
>      select, scrolling of long lists, opening the menu upwards when select
>      is against bottom of screen, to name a few.

There's a few more steps to accommodate different client setups and a tutorial linked for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this great article](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) about styling a select dropdown. There are limitations however and some older browsers will render the select box its own way.

It basically involves wrapping the select in a div and styling the div:

```css
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 268px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   }

.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(new_arrow.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
```

```html
<div class="styled-select">
  <select>
    <option>Here is the first option</option>
    <option>The second option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```